# Create a code that installs an application and runs only that application

Tags: android, ios

I need a device that runs only one custom application and does not allow the Users to access any other features. Building a complete device would involve a lot of time and money for sure(only if this can be done with android). This can usually done for each android device seperately. It could be better if there could be simply a piece of code that can be simply executed on the device that installs the application and at the same time restricts the device as per requirement. 
Could someone advice me a way to implement in the Android devices. Is it something possible :(
Would also like to know if the same is possible with iOS..
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be absolutely sure that users cannot do anything but accessing one specific app, the only way to do this is to create a [custom ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1801690) that allows to install your app only.